# Migration of NDIS versions

Tags: windows, migration, device-driver, ndis, network-driver

What is the major difference between NDIS 6.0 & NDIS 6.30?
Here is what information I know,

There was nothing like WWAN medium in case of NDIS 6.0. WWAN specific OID’s weren’t also available in NDIS 6.0. So TCP/IP use to send with 802.3 headers. Only WAN was present in NDIS 6.0.

Later on, from NDIS 6.20 onwards, the medium called WWAN was introduced where the TCP/IP was directly sending Raw IP packets.Also WWAN specific OID’s were introduced here after.

Is this correct?
And how to migrate from NDIS 6.0 version to NDIS 6.30?
What exactly do we need to do to change version? what does it affect?
The above question is wrt miniport driver implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN mostly describes the steps involved with porting NDIS drivers.

General information on porting/migration of NDIS drivers to newer version of NDIS drivers is present in this link :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh440157%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

NDIS 6.x to 6.3 migration information is present in this link :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh440156(v=vs.85).aspx